# Are the differences between these two regular expressions negligible?

Tags: javascript, regex

To answer the last exercise in the ninth chapter of Eloquent JavaScript, I wrote a regular expression that matches only JavaScript-style numbers.

**My regular expression:**

```
/^[-+]?(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?$/
```

syntax diagram: https://www.debuggex.com/r/-E6E-Vtk7RWMv5X9

**The author's regular expression:**

```
/^(\+|-|)(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE](\+|-|)\d+)?$/
```

syntax diagram: https://www.debuggex.com/r/CCeZTSHeRIxnNXXY

Are the differences between these two regular expressions negligible? Is there any string to which my regular expression will match but the author's won't, or vice versa?

Comment: For one the authors requires a + or a - while yours does not require one (plus 1 for makes better regexes)

Comment: @b729sefc: no plus/minus required. Note the "or nothing" `|)`.

Comment: actually the authors doesn't require a + or -, but the + or - is a group (in both cases)

Comment: Valid, far less readable, subsets are the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The author's creates backreferences you don't
2. `\d+\.?\d*` matches the same as `\d+(\.\d*)?`, but the latter is more effective engine-wise
3. You're forcing a match to the end of string with `$`

If you don't need the extra captures, they're both the same

---

> Is there any string to which my regular expression will match but the author's won't, or vice versa?

<s>Only if there's text after the number, e.g `1 abc`</s>

None, since last question edit

Comment: On a side note, `[-+]?` is more effective and cleaner